# Are directed graphs only possible with files that contains a "source" and "target" value?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, directed-graph

I got one question about the force-directed layout in d3.js. I try to understand if directed graphs are only possible with an JSON file, which contains a "source" and "target" value? I ask this, because i am using the hierarchy-layout for force-directed graphs and i could not find any examples with directed graphs AND hierarchy-layout, so i try to understand other examples and write my own.

Usually, hierarchy has this form (no "source" and "target"):

```
  "name": "frank",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "tim"
    },
    {
      "name": "max",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "alex"
        },
        {
          "name": "martin"
        },
        .....
```

Based on this example: http://bl.ocks.org/jhb/5955887

i would like to know, where is the line that makes clear how to set the arrows right (from source to value and not the other way). I copied and pasted the most important parts of the code and deleted some unimportant parts:

```
var dataset = {

    nodes: [
    {name: "Adam"},
    {name: "Bob"},
    {name: "Carrie"},
    {name: "Donovan"},
    {name: "Edward"},
 ...
    ],
    edges: [
    {source: 0, target: 1},
    {source: 0, target: 2},
    {source: 0, target: 3},
    {source: 0, target: 4},
    {source: 1, target: 5},
    {source: 2, target: 5},
 .....
    ]
    };


    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({"width":w,"height":h});

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(dataset.nodes)
        .links(dataset.edges)
        .size([w,h])
        .linkDistance([linkDistance])
        .charge([-500])
        .theta(0.1)
        .gravity(0.05)
        .start();



    var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
      .data(dataset.edges)
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("id",function(d,i) {return 'edge'+i})
      .attr('marker-end','url(#arrowhead)')
      .style("stroke","#ccc")
      .style("pointer-events", "none");

    var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(dataset.nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr({"r":15})
      .style("fill",function(d,i){return colors(i);})
      .call(force.drag)


    var edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath")
        .data(dataset.edges)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr({'d': function(d) {return 'M '+d.source.x+' '+d.source.y+' L '+ d.target.x +' '+d.target.y},
               'class':'edgepath',
               'fill-opacity':0,
               'stroke-opacity':0,
               'fill':'blue',
               'stroke':'red',
               'id':function(d,i) {return 'edgepath'+i}})
        .style("pointer-events", "none");

    svg.append('defs').append('marker')
        .attr({'id':'arrowhead',
               'viewBox':'-0 -5 10 10',
               'refX':25,
               'refY':0,
               //'markerUnits':'strokeWidth',
               'orient':'auto',
               'markerWidth':10,
               'markerHeight':10,
               'xoverflow':'visible'})
        .append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
            .attr('fill', '#ccc')
            .attr('stroke','#ccc');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your hierarchical data array to create a force directed chart, but first you'll have to modify that array to populate your `nodes` and `links` array.

So, given this data array:

```
var data = {
    "name": "Frank",
    "children": [{
        "name": "Tim"
    }, {
        "name": "Max",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Alex"
        }, {
            "name": "Martin"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Tom",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Murphy"
        }, {
            "name": "Amanda"
        }]
    }]
};
```

You can use this function to populate the nodes:

```
function flatten(hierarchyArray) {
    var nodes = [],
        i = 0;

    function recurse(node) {
        if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
        if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
        nodes.push(node);
    }

    recurse(hierarchyArray);
    return nodes;
};
```

And to populate the links:

```
links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
```

That way, you can have a force directed chart without explicitly setting "target" and "source".

Check the demo (the first console.log is for the nodes, the second one is for the links):

```js
var data = {
    "name": "Frank",
    "children": [{
        "name": "Tim"
    }, {
        "name": "Max",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Alex"
        }, {
            "name": "Martin"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Tom",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Murphy"
        }, {
            "name": "Amanda"
        }]
    }]
};

var nodes = flatten(data);
var links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

console.log(nodes);
console.log(links);

function flatten(hierarchyArray) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  recurse(hierarchyArray);
  return nodes;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

(source of the `flatten` function: [this bl.ocks from Bostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288))

Comment: wow, thanks to you again, Gerardo! You are truly a d3.js - genius! You work with it as a fulltime job?

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'm a biology teacher, I'm a freelancer coder (D3 only) as a secondary job.

Comment: Wow, i did not know you can use D3 to earn money. I thought folks just use it to play around for hobby and fun.

Comment: @DerickKolln since you're new at S.O., let me give you a tip: if an answer suits you, accept it/upvote it. That way, not only you "close" the problem, but people will be more inclined to help you the next time you ask. I can see that you *never*  accepted an answer.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the tip. I did not know about that option before you told. I will upvote now for sure. But you cannot see by now, because my reputation is under 15.

Comment: I must be blind, i cannot see it.

Comment: Hey Gerardo, i got one more question: i use an extern json-file, let's say "a.json"....i tried to change the line `var nodes = flatten(data)` into              `var nodes = flatten(a.json)`, but i did not work

Comment: also i would like to add: i am using v4, that means, some functions are changed, so  `var links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes)` should be                `var links = d3.tree().links(nodes)` now, but it still does not work

Comment: I just looked up at the D3 documentation, it says, that in v3                          `d3.layout.tree().links(nodes)` is available, but in v4 it is not listed anymore.

Comment: Please don't make questions in the comments. Post another question, thus someone else can help you.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. You don't have an idea, how to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, i just posted another new question (opened another thread), as you said. Sorry, i am new here and i do alot wrong.

Comment: Well, it's pretty easy: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . I checked again your profile and you *never* accepted *any* of the answers you got. If you keep ignoring the answers, people won't answer your questions anymore (I mean I won't).

Comment: Now i found it, i have accepted your answer. Thanks for the hint.